# Convert iPython Notebook to copy-proof format (e.g. png)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a rather long iPython Notebook that I want my students to reproduce in class. I don't just want to give them a pdf or notebook file as they would just copy the text, which defeats the purpose...

Is there a way for me to convert the notebook into a huge png, or copy protected format (e.g. with right click forbidden)?

Comment: Worth bearing in mind nowadays clever students might find workarounds via [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). That said, possibly this isn't the group that will have trouble with your assignment.

Comment: Haha @jpp. Agreed that they can probably pass my class then anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a fullsize screenshot of the notebook in the browser.

For Chrome it is possible with extensions or with builtin developer tools. [Guide](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/151-screenshot-capture/)

Newer Firefox versions has it [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots)

Comment: I had to first delete the header in the html (it prohibited the automatic scrolling done by the screenshot tool), but then FireShot did a great job. Saved straight to pdf too (but image-based pdf).